# Looping through array and create a new array of query results PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array object that can contain zero or more values like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => dkgasO05P2XpfyWW
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => LzE6G9UQIShOUoKq
    )

)
```

I want to loop through each value in this array and use the id in a query that returns an object that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => taWPlKGXHR5Y03cc
            [title] => Test Document Title
            [filename] => test.docx
        )

)
```

On each iteration of the loop the query returns with one result in the form of an array object.  I want to add the object to an array object that in this case would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => dkgasO05P2XpfyWW
            [title] => Test Document Title 0
            [filename] => test0.docx
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => LzE6G9UQIShOUoKq
            [title] => Test Document Title 1
            [filename] => test1.docx
        )
)
```

The query is written and working and I know I need to use a foreach loop to iterate over the array of IDs, but I don't quite get how to set it up so that the end result is an array object as listed just above.  I'm using PHP & Codeigniter to do all of this.

The code of the foreach I have so far is something like this:

```
$child = array();
foreach ($id as $row) {
        $child = $this->users_model->get_docnfo($id);
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: if you want that $child is the result array, then try $child[] = $this->users_model->get_docnfo($id);

Comment: Thanks Christian!!! I actually just got that piece working, so now I have the desired array of objects.  Now I have to figure out how to display the resulting array of objects.  Making progress, but not quite there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it with

```php
$child = array();
foreach ($id as $row) {
        $child[] = $this->users_model->get_docnfo($row->id);
}
```

Note the `$row->id` instead of `$id` and also the brackets after `$child`.